# Transfering from pandas dataframe to Geopandas?

Tags: geopandas, pandas, typeerror

I am not able to transfer a pandas dataframe column with geolocation coordinates into a Geopandas Point format.

```
location = pd.read_csv('City_addresses')
print location['Geolocation'].head()
```

Outputs the following:

```
0    (50.673675, -120.298973)
1    (50.678354, -120.329258)
2    (50.672496, -120.333317)
3    (50.673359, -120.332912)
4    (50.673411, -120.32978)
Name: Geolocation, dtype: object
```

Then I attempt to transfer it to Geopandas Point coordinates.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame

location['Geolocation'] = location['Geolocation'].apply(Point)
gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(location, geometry='Geolocation', crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})

print gpd
```

To which I get:

> TypeError: a float is required

But it won't allow me to change the datatype to a float in pandas either. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your coordinates are string representations of tuples, for example `"(50.673675, -120.298973)"` [but:](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)

> The Point constructor takes positional coordinate values or point
>   tuple parameters.

So you need to convert the string to `50.673675` and `-120.298973` or `(50.673675, -120.298973)`. You can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
location['geometry'] = location.Geolocation.apply(lambda x: Point(eval(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your coordinates are stored inside tuples. However, to construct a GeoPandas Object, you need a column usually named "geometry" which store shapely.geometry objects. In your case, the object needs to be Point objects. Therefore, the code to construct a GeoPandasDataFrame would look like:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

location = pd.read_csv('City_addresses')
location["geometry"] = location.apply(lambda x: Point(x["Geolocation"][0], x["Geolocation"][1]) , axis = 1)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(location, geometry='geometry', crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
```

Comment: You can also do: `location['geometry'] = location.Geolocation.apply(lambda x: Point(eval(x)))`

Comment: @yimcai Your solution is giving me a type error, says that the float type is required

Comment: @BERA good to know.

Comment: @user4718221 sorry I did not notice that (50.673675, -120.298973) is actually stored as String type "(50.673675, -120.298973)". My method requires some extra string parsing work. Instead, BERA provides a shortcut to save work to parse "(50.673675, -120.298973)"

Comment: @yimcai How would you go about swapping the coordinates places? Apparently it needs to be (-120.298973, 50.673675), and I wrote the script below for that. For some reason, its not working. Any ideas?    for u in gdf['Geolocation']:
    u = u.replace('(', '')
    u = u.replace(')', '')
    a, b = u.split(',')
    correct = [b, a]
    correct = gdf['Geolocation_correct']

Comment: @user4718221 I would suggest using regular expression to parse the string. try: import re; pattern = re.compile("\((.*?)\,(.*)\)"); text = '(50.673675, -120.298973)'; lat= float(pattern.match(text).group(1)), lng = float(pattern.match(text).group(2)).